# android notification comes up on start

Tags: java, android

I m trying to create a app, where i schedule a notification 
but whenever i try to open the app, the notification comes up.....
it comes up at the right time but also when the app is opened.
here's the code............

Main activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();



    Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,16);
    Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.MINUTE,18);
    Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);


PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
        0, myIntent,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);



alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis(),120000,pendingIntent);


}
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
  context.startService(myIntent);
}

}
```

NotificationService.java

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

private NotificationManager mManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}




@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(
                    this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.images,
            "xys", System.currentTimeMillis());

    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
            "xyz", "abcd",
            pendingNotificationIntent);
    notification.flags|= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    mManager.notify(0, notification);

    stopSelf();




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alarm is triggering again because after notification you are calling the MainActivity in which you are setting Alarm again. Try to set alarm in different activity. else prevent alarm from setting if activity started after notification.

Comment: You can do it using two ways.  1) Setting Alarm from different activity 2) Before setting alarm make sure current hour is not equal to 16. Edit you main activity with below code..               
if(Calendar_Object.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)!=16)                                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis(),120000,pendingIntent);